# Spark Cassandra write Dataframe, how to find which keys already exist in database during insertion

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, insert, duplicates, spark-cassandra-connector

I have written the following JAVA method to persist data for multiple POJO's to an Apache Cassandra database through Apache Spark.

This seems to work OK, however Spark does not provide any information on whether the records were inserted (keys do not exist in cassandra) or were updated (keys already exist in DB).

Is there a way with minimal cost (I would like to avoid loading the contents of the table in a dataframe and checking for duplicate keys), to find out at the time of the insertion which records already exist (have duplicate keys) in the DB?

The exact code is shown below:

```
@Service
public class WriteDB {

    @Autowired
    private SparkSession sparkSession;

    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WriteDB.class);

    public <T> void uploadData(List<T> objects, Class<T> clazz, String keyspaceName, String tableName) {

        LOG.info("Number of records to be committed to database: " + objects.size());

        //Create dataset from entity object
        Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(objects, clazz);


        //Write data from spark dataframe to cassandra schema
        df.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("keyspace", keyspaceName);
            put("table", tableName);
        }}).save();

        LOG.info("Records Commited");
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, do you use Cassandra or DSE

Comment: We are currently using the Apache distribution of Cassandra. Communication between Spark and Cassandra is realized using the  Dastax Cassandra connector.

Answer (score 1):

In Cassandra, everything is upsert - there is no distinction between inserts & updates.  Cassandra don't check if data exist or not when inserting or updating (except LWTs) - it just add data, and the previous copies are removed during compaction.

The only way to achieve your task is to load data from table - with Dataframe API it will be done on the level of Spark by reading whole table into Dataframe and then joining, or in RDD API by using `joinWithCassandra` or `leftJoinWithCassandra` (see [doc](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#using-joinwithcassandratable)).

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid this as the tables are very large, but it seems this is the only way.

Comment: But do you really need to know what is updated and what not?

Comment: The main reason is that we receive large packets of measurement data and we want to be able to log (or maybe return a warning) when duplicate data are inserted in the database.

Comment: You can do some optimizations, like, joining only primary key columns, not the whole data set, etc. But the joinWithCassandra could be still faster than join on the Spark level